# Grunt replace string in several files with a little difference

Tags: javascript, replace, gruntjs

I need to do similar replacements in several files using Grunt. I'm trying to use `string-replace` tasks, but unfortunately for each case i need to define a new task:

```
'string-replace': {
        de: {
            files: { 'public/de.html': 'src/templates/index.html' },
            options: { replacements: [
                { pattern: /<!-- @locale-vendor-replacement -->/ig, replacement: '<script src="js/i18n/angular-locale_de-ch.js"></script>'},
                { pattern: /<!-- @locale-name-replacement -->/ig, replacement: 'de'}
            ]}
        },
        fr: {
            files: { 'public/fr.html': 'src/templates/index.html' },
            options: { replacements: [
                { pattern: /<!-- @locale-vendor-replacement -->/ig, replacement: '<script src="js/i18n/angular-locale_fr-ch.js"></script>'},
                { pattern: /<!-- @locale-name-replacement -->/ig, replacement: 'fr'}
            ]}
        },

        ...
```

I wish to define a list of files or even a pattern, e.g. `public/(*).html`, and then specify replacement

```
"@placeholder" -> "<script src="js/i18n/angular-locale_$1.js"></script>"
```

or something like that. Any suggestions?